# Symfony Ajax Timeout AbstractObjectNormalizer

Tags: php, symfony, symfony4

My ajax request was working but started timing out, with the following error:

```
[Mon Aug  6 11:16:26 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/sibrax/SistemaSibrax/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyPath.php on line 140

[Mon Aug  6 11:16:26 2018] 127.0.0.1:47322 [500]: /produto/pedidos/consulta_codigo?produto_cod=1 - Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/sibrax/SistemaSibrax/vendor/symfony/property-access/PropertyPath.php on line 140
```

And sometimes this error:

```
[Mon Aug  6 11:17:37 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/sibrax/SistemaSibrax/vendor/symfony/serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php on line 89

[Mon Aug  6 11:17:37 2018] 127.0.0.1:47896 [500]: /produto/pedidos/consulta_codigo?produto_cod=2 - Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /home/sibrax/SistemaSibrax/vendor/symfony/serializer/Normalizer/AbstractObjectNormalizer.php on line 89
```

My function:

```
public function PedidoConsultaCodigo(Request $request) {

    if (! $request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
        throw new NotFoundHttpException();
    }

    $session = $this->get('session');
    $company = $session->get('company');

    $encoders = array(new JsonEncoder());
    $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceLimit(1);
    // Add Circular reference handler
    $normalizer->setCircularReferenceHandler(function ($object) {
        return $object->getId();
    });
    $normalizers = array($normalizer);
    $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

    // grab ajax request
    $cod = $request->query->get('product_cod');

    // get repository and do custom find
    $repo = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Product::class);
    $productObj = $repo->findByCod($cod, $company);

    // grab array
    $product = $productObj[0];

    // pass to JSON
    $jsonContent = $serializer->serialize($product, 'json');

    return new Response($jsonContent);
}
```

Someone know what is happening? I guess the problem is with the normalizer but I dont know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem, I just added

```
$normalizer->setIgnoredAttributes(array("company"));
```

and everything works again.
Entity relationships (product#company in my case) was causing the error, the normalizer was on infinite loop.